# Equivalence Relations Proof dealing 3 dividing x + y

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Consider the relation $S$ on the Natural Numbers defined by $\quad x\,S\,y\quad$ if $3$ divides $\quad x + y.\quad$ Prove $S$ is not an equivalence relation.

I know an equivalence relation is one that is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. I believe that S does not satisfy the reflexive property. For example, the element (2,2) would not be an element of S.

Is this correct? Also I am unsure how to state that formerly.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and where you got stuck so we can tailor our answers to the appropriate level and target them at the specific difficulty you have.

Comment: My apologizes, i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment, or I would make this into a comment:

You need to show:

i) Every element in the set is related to itself; in this case, $x\sim x$, meaning

$x+x$ is divisible by $3$.

ii) If $x\sim y$, then $y\sim x$, i.e., if $x+y$ is divisible by $3$, then so is $y+x$.

iii) If $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$, then $x\sim z$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Keep posting useful answers and you will soon be able to comment. :)

Comment: Ok, so i understand the symmetric argument. It would not be reflexive because of examples like x = 2 and y = 2. But what about the transitive. Is it just that if x+y divides 3 and y + z divides 3, then x+z divides 3?

Comment: You only need to show that any one of the conditions fails for it not to be an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

$3$ not necessarily divides $2x$.